# Variable selection in mixed linear integer programming or mixed integer programming with convex constraints and objective

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have a binary variable $b\in\{0,1\}$ and three real variables $x,y,z$.

If $b=0$ then I want $x=y$ and if $b=1$ then I want $x=z$.

1. Is this possible with mixed linear integer programming?
2. Is this possible at least with mixed integer programming with convex constraints and objective?

Comment: 1. yes; 2. you do not need nonlinear constraints

Comment: @LinAlg What is the program?

Answer (score 1):

You need just 4 constraints and a sufficiently large constant $M$:
$$x \geq y - bM$$
$$x \leq y + bM$$
$$x \geq z - (1-b)M$$
$$x \leq z + (1-b)M$$

Comment: Well can we avoid $M$?

Comment: @Brout maybe your solver supports indicator constraints. Otherwise you cannot without introducing something worse.

Comment: 'something worse' could it be in convex mixed integer programming?

Comment: @Brout my solution is convex and uses integers; there is just no magic trick to work around big-M